# Not all document properties can be edited with Contribute permission

Tags: 2013, document-library, permissions

User has Contribute permissions. When they edit a document's properties they cannot fill  a People Picker field but they can fill  the other fields

- When we were on 2007 they could and now we are on 2013 they can't. Has the Contribute permission changed between the versions?
- What permission do they need to add the name?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's a permission issue. I would rather look into the configuration of your "Profile Service". Review the permissions of the service, the farm account and the synchronization settings.

Comment: I assumed it was a permissions issue because of the message they could see.  Where would I find the Profile Service?

Comment: It can be rather complex. There are tons of tutorials online. A random one that I found : http://jaxsharepoint.blogspot.be/2013/08/setup-and-start-sharepoint-2013-user.html